# constructor in php with arguments issue

Tags: php

I'm not able to get the arguments passed onto a function in the constructor. Let me a bit clear with the code snippet below.

```
class Foo{
    public function __construct($arg){
         $arg = $arg1;
    }

    public function A($arg1){
        echo $arg1;
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
$data = $obj->A('hello');
```

Here, the call is being made to the function A with an argument. I'm not able to get the same argument value in the constructor. I'm just giving an idea of my code.

Comment: You can't access `$arg1` in your constructor, it comes from nowhere. Constructor is called only when you do `new Foo()`. You might want to read more about objects, and variable scope because it seems that you are mixing things. Or be more specific with what you want to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your code has errors in it! You can't create an instance from Foo without passing an argument to the constructor

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the value only when I do something like, $obj = new Foo('hello');

Comment: I just wanted to know if its possible at all to get the value without doing this. Looks like 'no'

Comment: Is it possible to load the function A automatically after the constructor is called as $obj = new Foo('hello') or do I need to call A specifically from the constructor?

Comment: `$arg` v.s. `$this->arg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Check your variable names! Do not attach numbers. Give them proper individual names to avoid errors.
- Read a bit on Constructors in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Some additional examples:

**Constructor Argument**

```
class Foo{
    public function __construct($argument){
        echo $argument;
    }
}

new Foo('Hello World');
```

**Constructor Argument + Set argument to object as property**

```
class Foo
{
    public $argument = '';     

    public function __construct($argument){
        $this->argument = $argument;
    }

    public function printIt()
    {
        echo $this->argument;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo('Hello World');
$foo->printIt();
```

Comment: method cannot has name `print`. it is *reserved* word

Comment: Is it possible to load the function A automatically after the constructor is called as $obj = new Foo('hello') or do I need to call A specifically from the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

In your `_construct`, `$arg1` is not available for use, since it doesn't come from anywhere. This code would work fine if you would just remove `$arg = $arg1;` and remove `$arg` from the parameters of your constructor.

Right now the constructor is trying to pass a value from a variable that doesn't exist on that scope to `$arg`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

class Foo {

    private $arg1;

    public function __construct($arg) {
        $this->arg1 = $arg;
    }

    public function A() {
        echo $this->arg1;
    }

}

$obj = new Foo("hello");
$data = $obj->A();
```

try this, it will work